# Error: snap "ubuntu-calculator-app" from channel "stable" (snap not found)

Tags: software-installation, 16.04

I run the following command:

```
sudo snap install ubuntu-calculator-app
```

but it shows me an error:

> error: cannot perform the following tasks:
>   - Download snap "ubuntu-calculator-app" from channel "stable" (snap not found)

**Output of `snap find`**

```
Name                Version                  Summary
audovia             3.2.2                    Database application for making music using JFugue MusicStrings
beagleblack         3.1                      OEM Beagle Bone Black
canonical-dragon    0.7.1                    The gadget snap for the dragonboard
canonical-i386      3.1.i386                 The gadget snap for generic i386 systems
canonical-pc        3.2                      AMD64 generic package
canonical-pc-linux  4.4.0-21+20160420.05-05  The ubuntu-core kernel snap
canonical-pi2       3.2                      Raspberry Pi 2 support package
hello-world         6.0                      Hello world example
http                4.6692016                HTTPie in a snap
morse-converter-py  1-2                      Simple command-line Morse converter
sudo                1                        not sudo
tor-middle-relay    0.2.7.6-6                Essential infrastructure node for Tor network
ubuntu-core         16.04+20160420.05-02     The ubuntu-core OS snap
xkcd-webserver      16.04-5                  Show random XKCD compic via a build-in webserver
```

I really don't know what i am missing.
How to resolve it?

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: @Jos what works for you?

Comment: The exact same command works for me. It starts downloading 60Mb, then 120Mb more, which seems to me quite excessive for a simple calculator, but anyway, it works. Perhaps you didn't have an Internet connection at the time?

Comment: @Jos I thought the same but i checked. There is internet connection

Comment: What does `snap list` do on your system?

Comment: @Jos Oh! IT shows no snaps found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39012/discussion-between-sha-and-jos).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also. In my case, it was because some packages were being held back from an upgrade, preventing the installation of the snap packages. So I had to do a

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

to install them.

At that point, I discovered that there was a conflict with one package that was holding back the packages from upgrading. I believe I had to do

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <package_name>
```

then an update to get it to resolve.

Comment: Actually it might have needed sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite <package_name>. In any case, maybe this will be helpful to you if your problem was similar to mine.